# How to Do Quality Assurance of Merged Videos?

Tags: video, merge

Code developed originally in the thread [How to order and merge many .ts files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225204/15504) which works in statically generated parts of videos to some extend but has limitations in the dynamic view

```
echo 'HRmasi4?.mp4-'{01..99}.ts | tr " " "\n" > tslist
echo 'HRmasi4?.mp4-'{100..500}.ts | tr " " "\n" >> tslist
while read line; do cat $line >> combined.ts; done < tslist
```

I am viewing the result and having a problem in controls. 
I can view everything smoothly in a row. 
However, if I move the location of the video any time anywhere the video gets stucked. 
You have to start once again the video from the very beginning in order to view it. 
I am testing the view in VLC.

I would like to study the video better. 
Probably, I should change something in the merging too. 
Actually, I think the merging process can be designed more dynamically

- I see duplicates in the postprocessing phase of video but not in the preprocessing phase by `fdupes -rd *`. This fact implies that the target system is dynamically changing the content into random parts. This implies me that I have to find duplicates in a line. I am not sure if you can do this by `fdupes`. TODO
- Calibration of the resolution. Do not let VLC automatically resize the video resolution. It will crash in the end because the automatisation can be easily confused. It would be great to know how you can control the automatic control of the view for the resolution. TODO

---

How can you do the quality assurance of video merging?